# How to do this background without image?

Tags: html, css, background

Is it possible to make such a background gradient as in the picture. I found that this can be done through a radial gradient, but for some reason my gradient is in a circle. 
Maybe it better to do with image?
[image]

How I can to do clear border like a picture.

```css
.block {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.8rem;
  height: 12.4rem;
  background-color: #F3F5F7;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(
      circle at bottom right,
      red,
      #ffffff 30%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/vlad3k-the-sasster/pen/RwPJPdE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can approximate it using two gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(130% 140% at 140% 160%,transparent 99%,#f3f5f7 100%),
    linear-gradient(to top,#f3f5f7,#dadcdd);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```